# How can I add text strings to some fields based on finding a text string found in a portion of another field

Tags: excel, database

How can I add text strings to a specific field in a record based on the contents of another field in that record?

One field in each record potentially contains four pieces of data I need to search for with text strings, and if present, I need to add corresponding text strings to another field, with | between multiple strings.

An example field might have content like this:

```
Some sentence that precedes the info:
This String
That String
*another sentence that precedes other info
A third string
And a fourth string
```

I'd need to search for "This String" "That String" "third string" and "fourth string", and in fields that had all four, add a string in the other field that read "this|that|third|fourth"

In a field that only had "This String" and "fourth string", the added field data would need to be "this|fourth"

Comment: Which database has the information?

Comment: Its currently provided in an excel spreadsheet. I wasn't sure how to tag my question.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I was able to figure out how to do the search/add in a field in Excel, so I have partly solved my question, but now I need to know how to combine the added fields with a | between, but only between fields containing data.

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*This string*",$B2,1),"This string"),"")`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was overthinking and trying to do it backwards.
I exported a CSV of just the reference column, used a text editor to find and replace the strings I needed to remove and then replace the returns with the stovepipes. Hope this helps someone else. :)